# When to use string interpolation in React Native?

Tags: react-native, string-interpolation

I know HOW to use string interpolation, but not sure when to use it. I have been teaching myself React Native lately, and the instructor used string interpolation on a button title. However, he didn't use it earlier in the course when he was passing a string variable into a Text tag.

Let me know if you need an example of what I am talking about.

Example:

**How come this doesn't work?**

```
<Button title='Hello my name is {myName}'/>
```

**But this does**

```
<Button title={`Hello my name is ${myName}`}/>
```

Comment: Yes add an example to be clear.

Comment: Edited my question with an exmaple, any help will be appreciated

Comment: Maybe [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#specifying-attributes-with-jsx) is what you are looking for?

Comment: Basically, you can use either `{any javascript expression}` or "some string". But it's not possible to use string interpolation directly which means `title=\`${myName}\`` wouldn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The { } indicate that what is contained within is a javascript expression.

String interpolation is javascript code.

When you do `${someText}` — React Native does not detect that this is javascript and reads it as just a string.

When you do {`${someText}`} — React Native realises that what is inside is Javascript and it needs to treat it as such and therefore String interpolation is valid and works.